# Specify an Inline Array to Custom Attribute in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, custom-attributes

I would like to know if there's any way to specify an inline array (lets say of strings)
to custom attribute on a property in vb.net.

I have the following example that doesn't compile in vb.net (.net 1.1):

```
Attributes.ManyToOne(New String() {"a", "b", "c"})> _
Public Property PaymentTerms() As PaymentTerms
```

The attribute is defined in another assembly as:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
 public class ManyToOne : System.Attribute
 {
  private string[] _columns;


  public ManyToOne(string[] columns)
  {
   _columns = columns;
  }

  public string[] Columns
  {
   get { return _columns; }
   set { _columns = value; }
  }
 }
```

I get compiler error when I feed the array to the custom attribute in vb.net.
I have no problem in C#, just vb.net. What is the correct syntax in this silly language?

Important: Using .net 1.1.

Comment: Works fine when I try it in VS2008.  My VS2003 install is long gone, you found a good reason to upgrade perhaps.

Comment: That's my fear. I am fearing, VB.net 1.1 doesn't support array declarations in the attributes. I need some one to verify that this is true for VB.net on .net 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in VB.net attribute declaration are not supported in .net 1.1 of the framework.